# Why is AdamOptimizer duplicated in my graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am fairly new to the internals of TensorFlow.  Towards trying to understand TensorFlow's implementation of AdamOptimizer, I checked the corresponding subgraph in TensorBoard.  There seems to be a duplicate subgraph named `name + '_1'`, where `name='Adam'` by default.

The following MWE produces the graph below.  (**Note that I have expanded the `x` node!**)

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.Variable(1.0, name='x')
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-1, name='MyAdam').minimize(x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    with tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/mwe') as writer:
        writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

[image]

I am confused because I would expect the above code to produce just a single namespace inside the graph.  Even after examining the relevant source files (namely [`adam.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py), [`optimizer.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py) and [`training_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc)), it's not clear to me how/why/where the duplicate is created.

**Question: What is the source of the duplicate `AdamOptimizer` subgraph?**

I can think of the following possibilities:

- A bug in my code
- Some sort of artifact generated in TensorBoard
- This is expected behavior (if so, then why?)
- A bug in TensorFlow

### Edit: Cleanup and clarification

Due to some initial confusion, I cluttered my original question with detailed instructions for how to set up a reproducible environment with TensorFlow/TensorBoard which reproduces this graph.  I have now replaced all that with the clarification about expanding the `x` node.

Comment: @P-Gn, I can reproduce the issue in 1.13.1.  See details in my edit.  Any ideas?

Comment: I now wonder if this would be more appropriate as a GitHub issue.  If so advised, I could copy-paste this into GitHub and delete the SO question.  (I don't have a good sense for where one should draw the distinction between GitHub issue and SO question.)

Comment: Also can't reproduce your error, both TF 1.12 and 1.13

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me.  I just provided *exact* steps to reproduce on GCP.  I'm more confused than ever about why others can't reproduce this.

Comment: @P-Gn, I can reproduce the issue on GCP outside of Anaconda (using python3 from apt).  Additionally I can reproduce it on my local machine.  Not once have I failed to reproduce this issue.  Do you realize that it's necessary to expand the "x" node in order to see the optimizers?  Otherwise you just see the single "Adam" node off to the right side, as in my screenshot.

Comment: Yes,  you're right,  how could i miss it.  Seems that it is the case with all optimizers,  that create additional values.  But it seems that it is mostly visualization issue,  cause i dont see any additional values in graph or savrd checkpoint

Comment: Whew!  I'm not crazy.  :)  Any idea why it would have its own namespace?  This was basically my original question: what's going on?

Comment: Right now I have no idea. But i don't see such behaviour in another cases. Maybe you could come up with another test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, just a perhaps questionable way of leaking outside of your own scope.

First, not a bug: The Adam optimizer is not duplicated. As can be seen in your graph, there is a single `/MyAdam` scope, not two. No problem here.

However, there *are* two `MyAdam` and `MyAdam_1` *subscopes* added to your variable scope. They correspond respectively to the `m` and `v` variables (and their initialization operations) of the Adam optimizer for this variable.

This is where choices made by the optimizer are debatable. You could indeed reasonably expect the Adam optimizer operations and variables to be strictly defined within its assigned scope. Instead, they choose to creep in the optimized variables' scope to locate the statistics variables.

So, debatable choice to say the least, but not a bug, in the sense that the Adam optimizer is indeed not duplicated.

**EDIT**

Note that this way of locating variables is common across optimizers -- you can observe the same effect with a `MomentumOptimizer` for example. Indeed, this is the standard way of creating [slots](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#slots) for optimizers -- see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.13.1/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py#L141):

```
# Scope the slot name in the namespace of the primary variable.
# Set "primary.op.name + '/' + name" as default name, so the scope name of
# optimizer can be shared when reuse is True. Meanwhile when reuse is False
# and the same name has been previously used, the scope name will add '_N'
# as suffix for unique identifications.
```

So as I understand it, they chose to locate the statistics of a variable within a subscope of the scope of the variable itself, so that if the variable is shared/reused, then its statistics are also shared/reused and do not need to be recomputed. This is indeed a reasonable thing to do, even if again, creeping outside of your scope is somewhat unsettling.

Comment: Ah!  So [`AdamOptimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L131-L132) calls [`_zeros_slot`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L1121-L1140) which in turn [calls](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L1135) `slot_creator.create_zeros_slot`.  However, it fails to pass on `slot_name` (which would be `m` or `v`), and so the corresponding slots are misleadingly named only after `AdamOptimizer` instead of `m` or `v`.

Comment: Yes, using `m` and `v` -- perhaps in combination with the optimizer name -- would probably have been clearer.